# No funciona sql_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, base-de-datos

Estoy tratando de crear un simple login y registro y me tope con un problema que no se me habia presentado, que basicamente es que por alguna razon que al escribir
`$userInfo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta);`
y luego `print_r` obtengo

```
Array ( [username] => hey 
        [email] => hey@gmail.com 
        [nacimiento] => 2021-07-14 
        [genero] => F 
        [contrasena] => ff 
        [id] => 23 
       )
...
```

Todo bien.

Pero en el momento en que quiero usar el indice "username" para alojarlo en una variable de `$_SESSION['username'] = $_userInfo['username']`, me da el siguiente error:

```
Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\profile\php\crear.php on line 38
```

Aqui el codigo completo

```
<?php 

include "../bd.php";
session_start();

$username = $_POST["username"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$nacimiento = $_POST["nacimiento"];
$contrasena = $_POST["contrasena"];
$ccontrasena = $_POST["ccontrasena"];

if(isset($_POST["enviar"])){
    if(empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($nacimiento) || empty($contrasena) || empty($ccontrasena)){
        echo "Es necesario completar todas las casillas";
    } else{

        if($contrasena !== $ccontrasena){
            echo "La contrasena no coincide";
        } else{
            
            $SELECT = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email' LIMIT 1";
            $consulta = mysqli_query($conn,$SELECT);
            $userInfo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta);
            print_r($userInfo); //aqui me muestra el array con la informacion del usuario

            if(!$consulta->num_rows > 0){

                $INSERT = "INSERT usuarios (username,email,nacimiento,genero,contrasena)
                            VALUES('$username', '$email', '$nacimiento', 'F', '$contrasena')";

                if(mysqli_query($conn,$INSERT)){

                    //pero al querer usarlo para guaradarlo en una variable de session, da error
                    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $userInfo['username'];
                    echo "Bienvenid@ ".$_SESSION['usuario'];

                    
                } else{
                    echo "Ha ocurrido un error mientras se guardaban tus datos en la base de datos";
                }

            } else{
                echo "Este correo ya fue registrado antes";
            }

        }

    }
}

?>
```

Extra: Probe con `isset()` para ver si definitivamente no exisitia y no, lo curioso que me resulta es porque entonces si pudo mostrarme todos los datos tras usar `print_r` ANTES de esta sentencia:

```
if(!$consulta->num_rows > 0){

                $INSERT = "INSERT usuarios (username,email,nacimiento,genero,contrasena)
                            VALUES('$username', '$email', '$nacimiento', 'F', '$contrasena')";

                if(mysqli_query($conn,$INSERT)){

                    //pero al querer usarlo para guaradarlo en una variable de session, da error
                    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $userInfo['username'];
                    echo "Bienvenid@ ".$_SESSION['usuario'];
```

Que incluso antes de esa sentencia pude crear una variable `$_SESSION["usuario"]` con `$userinfo["username"]`, pero al querer hacer lo mismo pero ahora dentro de esa sentencia obtengo error :(

Answer (score 0):

El detalle es que debes revisar las validaciones que quieres hacer porque al hacer la consulta:

```
$SELECT = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email' LIMIT 1";
$consulta = mysqli_query($conn,$SELECT);
$userInfo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta);
```

Y si ya existe el `email` la validación se pasa al `else` donde manda el mensaje

```
echo "Este correo ya fue registrado antes";
```

Y si no está registrado pasa al `INSERT`

```
$INSERT = "INSERT usuarios (username,email,nacimiento,genero,contrasena)
                            VALUES('$username', '$email', '$nacimiento', 'F', '$contrasena')";

    if(mysqli_query($conn,$INSERT)){
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $userInfo['username'];
        echo "Bienvenid@ ".$_SESSION['usuario'];
    }
```

**Pero en este punto la consulta no trae datos ya que el registro no existe y apenas lo insertó por eso marca el error.**

Para hacer que funcione puede hacer la consulta después del `INSERT` o tomar los valores directo del `POST`.

Puede ser así con `POST`:

```
$_SESSION['usuario'] = $username;
```

O así con la consulta:

```
if(mysqli_query($conn,$INSERT)){
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email' LIMIT 1";
  $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $userInfo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);

  $_SESSION['usuario'] = $userInfo['username'];
  echo "Bienvenid@ ".$_SESSION['usuario'];
}
```

Comment: Mmmm ya, joder como no me he dado cuenta de eso jaja Muchas gracias amigo

Comment: @Ranfring si te ayudo a resolver tu duta puedes marcarla para ayudar a otros